# Is there any reason to keep firewalld running on a virtual machine with host firewall?

Tags: centos, firewall, virtualization, proxmox, firewalld

I'm setting up a CentOS 8 virtual machine created under Proxmox. Even when I choose the `minimal` install, I'm getting `firewalld` installed and enabled by default.

If I activate Proxmox's built-in firewall, is there any reason why I should keep `firewalld` on the VM? Is there any scenario that could justify keeping the guest firewall active?

Comment: Yes, because you may have different requirements/settings for host and guest.

Comment: Belt AND suspenders.  Security is an onion and should have lots of layers.

Comment: This is a bit like suggesting to use firewalld on an EC2 instance when the filtering is already managed by the security group; isn't this redundant? I feel like apart from protecting from a configuration mistake at security group level, this is totally useless?

Answer (score 2):

In short: **yes, keep the firewall ON**.

The host firewall will protect the host itself, but it will not generally filter traffic for a full-fledged (ie: HVM) virtual machine or even a direct networked container.

Comment: Actually, Proxmox allows me to filter the traffic to the VM, for example `DROP` all incoming packets by default, and `ACCEPT` packets to selected TCP ports. In this case, what's the advantage of keeping firewalld enabled, and duplicating the rules?

Comment: @Benjamin I don't use Proxmox, but it sound as if it puts your VM behind NAT (ie: on a private subnet which is NATed on the public side). Anyway, I would continue to use a guest-side firewall.